# How to figure out if WPF button event is taking action

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wpf

Hello I am having trouble figuring out what the problem is with my Form. I have tried debugging and would give me this:

```
'ProjectDAD.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectDAD.exe): Loaded'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationProvider.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ProjectDAD.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectDAD.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ProjectDAD.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectDAD.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.UI.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'ProjectDAD.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectDAD.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Foundation.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'ProjectDAD.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectDAD.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'ProjectDAD.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectDAD.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[13388] ProjectDAD.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

No errors show up at all but every time I run the form, and click the button on the form, it wouldn't do anything. Wouldn't give me any errors. It's like the event doesn't run when I click the button.

Here is my Cs code for the form:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using ProjectDAD.Models.DB;

namespace ProjectDAD.Rental_Management
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for toRent.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class toRent : Window
{
    public toRent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource truckRentalViewSource = 
((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource) 
(this.FindResource("truckRentalViewSource")));
        // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
        // truckRentalViewSource.Source = [generic data source]
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource truckCustomerViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("truckCustomerViewSource")));
        // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
        // truckCustomerViewSource.Source = [generic data source]
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource truckPersonViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("truckPersonViewSource")));
        // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
        // truckPersonViewSource.Source = [generic data source]
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            TruckCustomer cust = new TruckCustomer();
            cust.Age = int.Parse(ageTextBox.Text);
            cust.LicenseNumber = licenseNumberTextBox.Text;
            cust.LicenseExpiryDate = licenseExpiryDateDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date;


            TruckPerson per = new TruckPerson();
            per.Address = addressTextBox.Text;
            per.Telephone = telephoneTextBox.Text;
            per.Name = nameTextBox.Text;


            int truckId = int.Parse(truckIdTextBox.Text);
            IndividualTruck truck = DataService.searchTruckByID(truckId);
            decimal priceTotal = decimal.Parse(totalPriceTextBox.Text);

            TruckRental toRent = new TruckRental();
            toRent.TotalPrice = priceTotal;
            toRent.RentDate = new DateTime();
            toRent.ReturnDate = new DateTime();
            toRent.Customer = cust;
            toRent.Truck = truck;
            truck.Status = "Rented";


            DataService.rentTruck(toRent, true);

            MessageBox.Show("Truck rented succesfully");


    }
}
```

}

Here is my Data Service cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ProjectDAD.Models.DB;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ProjectDAD
{
public class DataService
{
    public static void rentTruck(TruckRental toRent, bool isNewCustomer)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DAD_TruckRental_RGMContext())
        {
            if(!isNewCustomer)
            {
                ctx.Entry(toRent.Customer).State = EntityState.Unchanged;                 
            }
            ctx.Entry(toRent.Customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.TruckRental.Add(toRent);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public static IndividualTruck searchTruckByID(int truckid)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DAD_TruckRental_RGMContext())
        {
            return ctx.IndividualTruck.Where(t => t.TruckId == truckid).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }


  }
}
```

[image: What My form Looks like]

Comment: Where and how are you hooking up the `Button_Click` event handler to the `Button`? Your example is complete.

Comment: @mm8 When i created my sell button, I pretty much double clicked on it to create that button_click. So my xaml code for the button pretty much looks like this:  `<Button FontSize="25" Content="Sell" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="340,318,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Height="37"/>`

Comment: @GraceDelosReyes put `Click="Button_Click"` on your XAML code of button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hook up your event handler in your XAML:

```
<Button FontSize="25" Content="Sell" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="340,318,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Height="37"
        Click="Button_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the button bindings and make sure it's properly bound to the click handler. 
You can use "Snoop" to see the visual tree,runtime bindings and all the properties. It also shows what events been fired by the UI. You can find it [here](https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf) .
Hope this helps.